# Getting HTML of dynamically generated code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [Bootstrap-Form-Builder](https://github.com/minikomi/Bootstrap-Form-Builder) to generate dynamic HTML forms. [Here is an example](http://minikomi.github.io/Bootstrap-Form-Builder/).  It's working just perfect.

Now I need to create a static page with the code rendered in the rendered tab. My problem is that I am unable to get the rendered code because it's made dynamically. I tried to get the data using jQuery, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        alert($("#build").clone().html());
    });
});
```

`#btn` is a button I added and `#build` is the id of a div where the form is dynamically generated. I was able to get the whole information including the setting HTML of the form. What I want is only the rendered area's HTML.

Here is the code that showed up when using `alert($("#build").clone().html());`:

```
   <form id="target" class="form-horizontal">
   <fieldset><div data-html="true" data-trigger="manual" data-title="Form Name" data-content="<form class='form'>
   <div class='controls'>
   <label class='control-label'> Form Name </label>
   <input class='input-large field' data-type=&quot;input&quot; type='text' name='name' id='name' value ='Form Name' />
   <hr/>
   <button id=&quot;save&quot; class='btn btn-info'>Save</button><button id=&quot;cancel&quot; class='btn btn-danger'>Cancel</button>
  </div>
 </form>
 " class="component"><!-- Form Name -->
 <legend>Form Name</legend>
 </div></fieldset></form>
```

As you can see, it contains extra data not provided in the rendered area.  Please ask me if something is not clear.

Comment: How are you adding the DOM??

Comment: Check out this example sir http://minikomi.github.io/Bootstrap-Form-Builder/

Comment: If possible, can post `$("#build").clone().html()` `html` ? Not same as "rendered area html." ? Thanks

Comment: @codegeek Never tried `Form-Builder` . Not certain what "It contains extra data not provided in the rendered area" is ? If possible , can indicate "extra data" ? Thanks